# Organizing Columns and Rows in R

Tags: r

I have a large set of financial statements imported into R and need to summarize the account names (VarN in the example below) by the column Years (YN) below and by amount (vN) below.  I have searched for solutions using reshape and dplyr, but to no avail.
I have:

```
Var1 Y1 v1
Var2 Y1 v2
Var3 Y1 v3
Var1 Y2 v4
Var2 Y2 v5
Var3 Y2 v6
```

I need to convert to:

```
     Y1  Y2  
Var1 v1  v4
Var2 v2  v5 
Var3 v3  v6
```

Comment: a reproducible example would be helpful

Comment: Sorry what do you mean - actual data in the tables above?

Comment: @Josh.D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example, and [mcve]

Comment: You can also search *long to wide format*:)

Answer (score 0):

Using reshape library on a dataframe df :
http://www.statmethods.net/management/reshape.html

```
library(reshape)

column1 <- c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3", "Var1", "Var2", "Var3")
column2 <- c("Y1", "Y1", "Y1", "Y2", "Y2", "Y2")
column3 <- c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6")


df <- data.frame(column1, column2, column3)
x <- c("Var", "y", "v")
colnames(df) <- x

mdata <- melt(df, id=c("Var", "y"))
cast(mdata, Var ~ y, value = 'v')
```

Don't forget to melt the data first.